# How do I initialize the Docusign Embedded Sending View to the first screen

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the REST API V2. I've successfully used the API to created an envelope from a document. In the request body, I embedded a document and json data for a recipient.  I then used the API to embed the sender page (Embedded Sending View) inside our website.  However, it initializes to the "tagging" screen.  The user can click the "Go Back" link to go to the first screen in the process but I would like to start them off on that screen.

1) Is that possible? If so, how?

2) Also, it's my understanding that we can remove/hide the "Documents for Signature"  and "Envelope Settings" sections from the first screen.  How is that accomplished?

I have screenshots but am unable to attach them to this post because I do not have a "10 reputation" (this is my first post).  I can email them to you directly if that's helpful.

Comment: I've modified my answer to show you how you can start out on the first page of the sending process, please review and accept as answer if it works for you.  Cheers, -Ergin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you modify the embedded signing URL that gets returned you can actually have it start you out on the first page of the sending process.  When you generate a signing url it will end with the string **`send=1`**.  If you modify that string to end with **`send=0`** then it will start you out on the first page of sending instead of the tagging page.

As for your other questions, you can alter the "Envelope Settings" by disabling/enabling options through the DocuSign Console.

---

For instance, to disable the option labeled

```
Allow recipient(s) to change signing responsibility
```

Go to Preferences -> Features and uncheck **Signers can re-assign envelopes** option.

---

To disable/enable the option

```
Allow recipients to edit the document(s)
```

Preferences -> Features -> **Allow Markup**.

---

As for the Reminders and Expirations section, this has a whole settings page devoted to it.  See Preferences -> **Reminders and Expirations**.  And if you have access to vaulting settings see Preferences -> Features -> **eVault**.  (Note that for this one in particular you might need your DocuSign Account Manager to enable/disable the setting for your account.